# Gridview is not working in Ajax Update Panel with Drop Down List inside it

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

On a web form with a Drop Down List on it and an Ajax update Panel.I also used a Script Manager.There is a Grid View inside the update panel.I used data source to bind the Drop Down List selected values with the Grid view.The values will be extracted from the specified tables of the database.
Every time I select a drop down list value , there should be corresponding data in the Grid view.But its not working , not giving an error but giving wrong outputs showing Grid view data for only one Drop Down List selected value.
Here's the HTML Code:-

```
         <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default5.aspx.cs"      Inherits="Default5" %>

         <!DOCTYPE html>

          <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <head runat="server">
          <title></title>
          </head>
          <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <br />
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <br />
            Select Deptt:
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</div>
</form>
```

Back end code :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Default5 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add_Dep();

}
private void Add_Dep()
{
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbdep", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "dname";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "dno";
    DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();

}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String qry = "select * from tbemployee where edno=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

}

Comment: Post your backend code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is problem in your page load. Add ispostback checking in Pageload.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
      Add_Dep();
   }
}
```

Comment: If I use Drop Down List outside the update panel.Will it work the same way?

Comment: It is not working when DDL used outside.It simply does not show any data

Comment: yes,it is not working this time in a different webform.Is there any changes when DDL is used outside the update panel?

Comment: Oh i got, u have set UpdateMode="Conditional" in update panel it means panel content refreshed if post is made occur from inside panel. So if u put DDL outside panel set this property UpdateMode="Always". For further reference check this link. http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/05/24/updatemode-default-value-for-the-updatepanel-is-always.aspx